# PHP how to trim a filename

Tags: php

i have a file in a directory named '`achieve3000_Gestalt_students102713.txt`'.. i want to reduce the file name to `Gestalt_students` ONLY

Have tried using `explode()` which gives something different altogether and preg replace

Please help

EDIT

i have 4 files

- achieve3000_Gestalt_students102713.txt
- achieve3000_Gestalt_teachers102713.txt
- achieve3000_Perspectives_Middle_Academy_students102713.txt
- achieve3000_Perspectives_Middle_Academy_teachers100913.txt

Comment: What specifically did you do when you tried `explode` and `preg_replace` that didn't work?

Comment: Is it just this one specific file, or are there list of files where we can figure out a pattern to work on?

Comment: Is: `achieve3000` a constant length?

Comment: hey Justin..please see edited question

Comment: hey Mark..explode gives me one character only as it 'splits' the string but i want like for example 'Perspectives_Middle_Academy_teachers'

Comment: hey Sutandiono..please see edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file name always begins with a character sequence whose length is equal to the length of `"achieve3000_"` (which is 12) and the number at the end is always 6 digits plus a 4 character extension sequence. The you can use this code

```
$output = substr($input, 12, strlen($input) - 22);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump(substr('achieve3000_Gestalt_students102713.txt', 12, 16));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)?

Like :

```
$input = "achieve3000_Gestalt_students102713.txt";
$answer =substr ($input, 12, 16); 
echo $answer;
```