# short filename if it's too long but keep the files extension

Tags: php

i have this function to shorten the filename if it is over 23 characters to "...", but i want to keep the files extension

```
function formatNameFile($nama) {
    return strlen($nama) > 23 ? mb_strimwidth($nama, 0, 23, "...") : $nama;
}

 echo formatNameFile('resume_t8ffvwnjxibqwhu5l0mk1jwu9mmb4b_3.pdf');
```

my output

> resume_t8ffvwnjxibqw...

expected output

> resume_t8ffvwnjxibqw...pdf

how do i achieve this? please help.

Comment: You need to separate handling of filename and file extension into 2 separate functions

Comment: I hope one of these work for you. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259002/how-to-truncate-filename-from-end-with-limit), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639047/php-how-to-trim-a-filename), [3](https://www.codercrunch.com/question/1530797269/how-limit-file-name-given-length-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate handling of filename and file extension.

```
<?php
function formatNameFile($nama) {
    $array = explode('.', $nama);
    $extension = end($array);
    $newName = strlen($nama) > 23 ? mb_strimwidth($nama, 0, 23, "...") : $nama;
    return $newName.$extension;
}

 echo formatNameFile('resume_t8ffvwnjxibqwhu5l0mk1jwu9mmb4b_3.pdf');
```

Comment: If you want unicode supported in file name, use `mb_strlen()` instead of `strlen()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one-liner with pathinfo() and implode() to get the name and extension of the file, truncate the filename to your desired length and then join them back together.

```
$shorterfilename = implode([substr(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME), 0, 23), pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)], '.');
```